# Buddypress, replacing a function added by a plugin-class

Tags: function, plugins, replace, buddypress

In bp-custom.php I try to replace a function added by the bp-groupblog-plugin (in bp-groupblog-classes.php). I can add my customized function bud i can’t remove the original and i’m getting the HTML for both functions displayed on my page.

I tried different hooks, altered the priority etc but nothing works yet. How can I remove the original function?

Thanks for any ideas.

Code:

```
function replace_bp_groupblog_signup_blog() {
    remove_action('bp_groupblog_create_screen_markup', 'bp_groupblog_signup_blog');
    remove_action( 'bp_groupblog_edit_screen_markup', 'bp_groupblog_signup_blog' );

    function my_bp_groupblog_signup_blog($blogname = '', $blog_title = '', $errors = '')
    {
         // all the code
    }
    add_action( 'bp_groupblog_create_screen_markup', 'my_bp_groupblog_signup_blog');
    add_action( 'bp_groupblog_edit_screen_markup', 'my_bp_groupblog_signup_blog' );
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'replace_bp_groupblog_signup_blog' );
```

UPDATE:

Changing the remove-action solved the problem:

```
add_action(
  'bp_groupblog_create_screen_markup',
  function() {
      remove_action( current_filter(), 'bp_groupblog_signup_blog' );
  },
  9
);
```

found the solution [here](https://plus.google.com/102976519828493552156/posts/gwXb3RoBavA)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to bp-custom.php:

```
remove_action( 'bp_groupblog_create_screen_markup', 'bp_groupblog_signup_blog' );
remove_action( 'bp_groupblog_edit_screen_markup', 'bp_groupblog_signup_blog' );

function my_bp_groupblog_signup_blog() {
     // all the code
}
add_action( 'bp_groupblog_create_screen_markup', 'my_bp_groupblog_signup_blog' );
add_action( 'bp_groupblog_edit_screen_markup', 'my_bp_groupblog_signup_blog' );
```

Comment: I’m still getting the HTML-output for both functions. The old function hasn't been removed. Thanks for the answer though.